# Will the Split gem for RoR always provide the same side of an AB test to a given user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ab-testing

I am considering using Split for AB testing: https://github.com/andrew/split.  The README says that "By default Split will store the tests for each user in the session."  You can optionally configure it to use a cookie or redis to store the tests instead.

If the test is stored in the session by default, then does this mean that a user might experience different sides of the AB test between different sessions?  If a user visits a site on two separate days, won't that necessarily be two different sessions?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you have sessions configured.  If your session cookie expires when the browser is closed or after a given time, you will get different version for that user (potentially).

I've released an integration with Google Analytics' Experiments API that is persistent (it uses cookies).  You can find it here https://github.com/dlangevin/gxapi_rails

Comment: Curious does this still work with Universal GA?  I'm having problems implementing a test with Split that has different sections of different partials sharing the same experiment:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251236/rails-a-b-testing-with-split-multiple-views-sharing-same-experiment-helper-met

Comment: It should.  Content experiments are standalone that shares data with Google Analytics.  I haven't seen anything that would suggest any modifications to the content experiment code would be necessary